# Use of 3 phase transformers which are ∆-Y connected and Y-∆ connected

Tags: power-supply, transformer, transmission-line, power-engineering

[image: source 1][image: source 2 image 1][image: source 2 image 2]

Different literatures say different things regarding ∆-Y and Y-∆ 3 phase transformer connection...

Some say that ∆-Y is used for step down and Y-∆ is used for step up while others say just the opposite things...

Depending on this step up and step down ability they are used in transmission and distribution of power... So please can anyone explain me what are ∆-Y and Y-∆ actually used for(which for step up and which for step down) along with a mathematical reason...
Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: Looks to me that your second source is internally contradictory.  On the two pages it calls both arrangements step-down.  I'd be suspicious.

Comment: It's a transformer and can be used (with the appropriate turns ratio) for step-up, step-down or 1:1.

Comment: So please can you explain me what you know... I am in great turmoil regarding this issue as I cannot make it out as to what shall be the answer actually...

Comment: I just have - it's anything you design it to be.

Comment: @Andy aka I know that as well... But which is more apt to be used

Comment: @Andy aka pls help me regarding this issue

Comment: it's whatever is demanded by the design requirements.

Comment: @Andy aka had it been so simple I guess the author of book would have written the same thing but the issue is quite ambiguous I think

Comment: For the same winding on each leg, the wye-delta has a 'built-in' step-down ratio of sqrt(3) and delta-wye the same step-up, reinforcing the claim of the first source, but there's no practical reason that you need to keep all the coils similar, so other factors, including the availability of a neutral for separating out single phase supplies can overrule this advantage.

Comment: @Phil G thanks your explanation is worth mentioning... However I have another though pondering in my mind... Many literatures say that the ∆-Y is a best method for distribution purpose as the secondary is having a 3 phase 4 wire system which can supply both 3 phase as well as 1 phase lighting circuits. Now if ∆-Y has to be used at the distribution end , it necessarily has to be a step down and not a step up... What do u feel??? Is it what you said about overruling this advantage at the end of your answer??